# The future of “Beer, Wine & Spirits”

Tags: discussion, status-completed

**Update:** Barring anything unforeseen, the switch is scheduled for Monday, May 9. Hold on to your beer mugs, wine glasses, and whiskey tumblers.

---

Recently, we solicited a thread to [Propose a new name for Beer SE!](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/propose-a-new-name-for-beer-se)

As you can see from the diverse responses, voting, and comments... ***naming is hard!*** You can never satisfy everyone's vision of how a community as diverse as this one should be labeled. So I compiled all of your suggestions and shared the various points and discussions with the Community Team.

An expanded Beer + Wine + Spirits site has all the pieces of an interesting community; we are very enthusiastic to see this initiative finally take hold — we just need a name to capture the *entire* scope.

We had to bend a few of our naming conventions for sites, but I think I've finally gathered enough support to move forward with a really comprehensive and straight-forward name for this site:

- **Name:** Beer, Wine & Spirits
- **URL:** [alcohol.stackexchange.com](http://alcohol.stackexchange.com)

Given the history and future direction of this site, I thought a comprehensive and simply-stated name would work best for this site. The scope of the site is for all alcoholic beverages and while many of the proposals were fantastic, they weren't necessarily clear what the site was about.

We're excited to get the new site name and URL in place immediately.

Any questions?

Comment: Beer, Wine & Spirits sounds like the Bed, Bath & Beyond of alcohol, I can't help but to think of a store when I say that name out loud; I don't like it but I guess that that's one of the downsides of not having a lot of traffic in meta, administrative decisions have to taken from time to time.

Comment: @JustDoIt: I thought [BevMo!](http://www.bevmo.com/about/) was the Bed, Bath & Beyond of alcohol.

Comment: emphasis on the words **sounds like** @JonEricson

Comment: Also I think 8 days for a low traffic meta site is not enough to get a proper perspective of what the users think, but at the same time that input might be as good as it gets :(

Comment: @JustDoIt: Ignore my snark. It's going to be pretty hard to land on a perfect name if we had all the time in the world.

Comment: That's definitely part of the problem that we're trying to solve @JustDoIt. We need more users to engage on the site. The post to propose a new name had very few views and very few votes. We can't leave this waiting forever, we need to make a decision to move the site forward.  **Naming is hard** for everything, we're excited for the change because it's pretty clear what the site is about based on the name.

Comment: That works -- and we can save the "cleverer" names for a possible rename of the site's chat room.  (Note that it's not a full enumeration -- mead and cider are also on-topic -- but we don't want a full enumeration anyway, just enough to suggest some bounds.)

Comment: ...but, coukd I trouble you for an Oxford comma? Pretty please? (Am I about to call down a firestorm?)

Comment: I am cool with your decision but why did you not propose that name and see what reaction it got?  Link is not active.

Comment: Yeah I understand @bluefeet I'm still gonna visit the site regardless of the name but the low input and traffic in meta worries me

Comment: It could be that most people will be drawn to the site because of the questions. That is how I always end up on stack exchange. I search for a solution to a problem in google and some SE forum comes up. The popular gaming forum doesn't have an obvious name, neither does 'Seasoned Advice'. At least not a name that people would search for often. I think the site should have a name that includes more. Unlikely that a site just on Cider would be able to sustain itself, where else would it go but here? I am fond of 'Open Bar'. It covers it all plus opens up for questions on serving etc.

Comment: Q: When are these changes going live?

Comment: @JustDoIt We're in the process of making all the changes.